# Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause'

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, face-recognition

I actually I'm working in an attendance system based on facial recognition.
But unfortunately, I'm facing  a problem with Mysql to record attendance

```
 if True in matches:
    first_match_index = matches.index(True)
    name = known_face_names[first_match_index]  

    sql = "UPDATE stud_att SET P1=1 WHERE name = fname"
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    mydb.commit()



  draw.rectangle(((left, top), (right, bottom)), outline=(255,255,0))


      text_width, text_height = draw.textsize(name)
      draw.rectangle(((left,bottom - text_height - 10), (right, bottom)), fill=(255,255,0), outline=(255,255,0))
      draw.text((left + 6, bottom - text_height - 5), name, fill=(0,0,0))



    del draw
```

Here is my code the problem is `Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause'`
I don't know where is the wrong I'm sure the name that the system was recognized is Existing in the database!

My table

```
fname, lname, ID, P1, P2, P3, P4
Name1,  Name2, 1,
```

Comment: Show us your table stud_att  usually mysql isn't wring in this things

Comment: If I understand it correctly, fname is one of your column names and not name, right?

Comment: @streof Yes fname is the column name

Comment: Then you have to swap their places and make sure that you concatenate `name` as a variable and not as a literal string

Answer (score 1):

```
sql = "UPDATE stud_att SET P1=1 WHERE fname = " + name
```

your column name must be on the left side of the `=` and then compare it to the value you want to check.

Comment: Unknown column 'Name1' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is a quoting issue: in SQL, strings need to be surrounded with single quotes; assuming that `name` is a string, you would need:

```
mycursor.execute("UPDATE stud_att SET P1 = 1 WHERE fname = '" + name + "'")
```

But this is error-prone to write, and still leaves you your code to SQL injection. So: you should just use a parameterized query:

```
mycursor.execute("UPDATE stud_att SET P1 = 1 WHERE fname = %s", (name))
```